# SaveAll do JpaRepository mantém o estado de persistência na memória?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, jpa, persistência

O JpaRepository nos oferece as opções `save` e `saveAndFlush` para persistir os objetos para o banco de dados. Diferentemente do `saveAndFlush`, o `save` mantém o estado de persistência em memória, o que acaba gerando problemas de memória em algumas aplicações.

Como não existe um método "*saveAllAndFlush*" a pergunta é: Ao utilizarmos o `saveAll`, ele também mantém o estado em memória? Seria necessário uma chamada de flush ou commit explicitamente?

Comment: Você está utilizando hibernate como implementação do JPA? E outra, talvez você esteja confundindo a aplicação e o funcionamento do método, o `save` mantém o estado de persistência em memória até o `commit` ou o `flush` ser realizado apenas.

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando como implementação do JPA. Sim, eu sei que o `save` mantém até o `flush` ou o `commit`, mas e quanto ao `saveAll` ele mantém em memória da mesma forma ou ele automaticamente faz o `flush`?? Essa é a questão